# YAML data format for mongodb collections and referenced entities

Tags: scala, mongodb, playframework, yaml

I want to load test data in my scala play application from data.yml file
which is in [YAML](http://yaml.org/) format.

My entities looks like:

```
@Entity("users")
User(@Required val uname: String, val isAdmin: Boolean = false)  {
  @Id var id: ObjectId = _

  @Reference val accounts = new ArrayList[Account]

}


@Entity("account")
class Account {

   @Id var id: ObjectId = _

  @Embedded val addresses = new ArrayList[Address] 
  @Reference val departments = new ArrayList[Department]  

  var description : String = _

}


class Address {
  street: String = _
  city: String = _

}

@Entity("department")
class Department {

 @Id var id: ObjectId = _

  principal: String = _ 

}
```

This is what almost a blank data.yml look like:

```
User(foo):
    uname: Foo
    accounts:
```

I want to load one user with 2 accounts. One of the account has just one address and one department, the other account has 2 addresses and one department to keep things as simple as possible. So what the complete yml data looks to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just use lists with keys? Using the '- key' notation or '[key1, key2]'? Example:

```
Department(dep1):
   ..

Address(address1):
   ..

Address(address2):
   ..    

Account(account1):
   ..
   addresses:
       - address1
   departments:
       - dep1

Account(account2):
   ..
   addresses:
       - address1
       - address2
   departments:
       - dep1  

User(user1):
  ..
  accounts:
     - account1
     - account2
```

Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaml#Lists